# How to replace target of binding (silverlight 4.0)

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

Problem description: In my Silverlight application (4.0), I have a TextBox control, which background is bound to some source property. I created a behavior for TextBox control. Inside my behavior, I want to take that binding, and "redirect" to other target (lets say, to the behavior itself). In other words, when the source property of background binding is changed, instead of updating property on TextBox control, I want to update some another target property. How to do that? I tried reflection, but it not allowed in SL on private fields...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the existing `Binding` using [FrameworkElement.GetBindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). Here's a sample:

```
FrameworkElement yourControl = null; // the code to get the control goes here
BindingExpression bindingExpression =
    yourControl.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.Background);
Binding binding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding; // it's your binding
```

Then, create a new `Binding` object, setup its properties (change target if required) and use `SetBinding` to attach it.

**UPDATE**

Now about the binding source.

Note that `Source` property will be non-null only if you set this property explicitly.

Other options for the `Binding` source include:

1. specific element: used if `Binding.ElementName` property is set
2. templated control: used if `Binding.RelativeSource` is set to a `RelativeSource` with `Mode=RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent`
3. binding target control: used if `Binding.RelativeSource` is set to a `RelativeSource` with `Mode=RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent`
4. `DataContext`: if neither `Source`, nor the previous 3 options apply.

If you want to clone a `Binding`, you should check all these options.

However, if you just need the data item, you'd better use `BindingExpression.DataItem` property, which should return the actual data item that is the binding source.

Comment: To Pavel: I tried that, but for some reason the "Source" of returned binding is null. The prevents to reuse this binding or to build another one based on this... By the way, the Path of returned binding looks perfectly OK.

Comment: BindingExpression.DataItem is null, just as all rest of the properties. Did you tested your answer on Silverlight 4?

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem was, that at the point when Behavior was attaching, the binding was kind of not initialized. The BindingExpression was there, with correct path, but DataItem and all the properties was not initialized yet (and were null-ed). The workaround I did: I subscribed to background change (by using intermediate DependencyProperty on proxy object) and when I received a callback, the binding was fully initialized and I did what I wanted to. I hope this will help someone, anyway thank you Pavel for the effort you done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to "redirect". Is it still ok if the text in the textbox changes? If you're trying to do binding to another element on the screen, you can use Element binding that would occur after the tb1 textbox loses focus:

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Source=Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In a behavior, you can us the TextChanged event and capture it there.

```
public class TextBoxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
/// <summary>
/// Called after the Behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.</remarks>
protected override void OnAttached()
{
base.OnAttached();
this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_TextChanged);
}

/// <summary>
/// Called after the Behavior is detached from an AssociatedObject.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.</remarks>
protected override void OnDetaching()
{
base.OnDetaching();
this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= new TextChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_TextChanged);
}

void AssociatedObject_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AssociatedObject.Text))
{
 string enteredValue = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
// do what you want with the entered value
}

// if you want to reset it.. this.AssociatedObject.Text = string.Empty;
}
}
```

Comment: To Aligned: I don't have control over the XAML. I trying to develop a Behavior, which will affect any TextBox, no matter where it applied. In example I provided, The user inside its XAML sets a binding to TextBox's background. But after he applying my behavior, I want (from inside of behavior) to take that background, and change it to something else (let say, I want to marge original background with another Brush). If I will know how to extract current value from bound DependencyProperty, that will be half step to victory. I was trying to use GetValue - returns nothing.